# Understanding a loop output

Tags: c++, for-loop

Can somebody explain to me why the output will be as follows?

Why the loop runs a second time after (int i) gets as value 9, which is not less than 5?

It seems that even if (int i) is greater than 5 it still adds another 3 but the body won't run a second time. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i=0;

int main()
{
for(;i<5;i+=3){
i=i*i;
}
cout << i << endl;

//Output:  12(i)
```

Comment: The second time is *when* it becomes 9.

Comment: Whenever it becomes 9 why the body won't run?(And just get 9+3?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works that way, more or less:

```
i = 0
i < 5 ? yes, keep on
i*i = 0
i+=3 => i ==3 now
i < 5 ? yes, keep on
i*i = 9
i+=3 => i is 12 now
i < 5 ? no, exit loop
```

You write a `for(initialization; condition; excuteAtTheEndOfCycle)`:
`initialization` is executed only once at the beginning, `condition` is evaluated before  each cycle, `excuteAtTheEndOfCycle` (`i+=3`, in your case), it's executed at the end of each cycle, before a further evaluation of `condition`

Comment: Thanks! I will mark it as correct soon. Before that , I didn't know it checked the condition only after making the addition.

Answer (score 0):

it is not running because you are giving condition of the loop to be less than five,
What are you want ,that output will be?

Comment: As mentioned //Output:  12(i)! But I've got my answer. Thanks anyway!